# Mysql: how to fetch ratings data

Tags: mysql

I want to get each feed with its corresponding `rating`.
I have this `mysql` query

```
    SELECT
    user_feed.*, COALESCE(SUM(feed_rating.rating), 0) AS rating
FROM
    user_feed
LEFT JOIN
    feed_rating
ON
    feed_rating.feed_id = user_feed.id
```

But it returns only one row when in fact I have `2 user_feeds`.
If I remove the aggregate function sum, it returns the two user_feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group by` with `SUM`

```
group by feed_id
```

Try this query

```
 SELECT
    user_feed.*, COALESCE(SUM(feed_rating.rating), 0) AS rating
FROM
    user_feed
LEFT JOIN
    feed_rating
ON
    feed_rating.feed_id = user_feed.id group by feed_id
```

> aggregate function performs a calculation on a set of values and
>   returns a **single value**